# No such table exists php POST file

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I am receiving a file via (sqlite file) and trying to connect to it using sqlite3. I tested this all using a sqlite file that was already on there on the server but now that im trying to do it when it gets uploaded I am trying to do operations to it.

I am  getting the error that not table exists but I know it does because i open it sqlite manager and verify it is there. here is a snippet of code

```
$folder = '/var/www/uploads/';
if ( !file_exists($folder) ) {
mkdir ($folder, 0777);
}
$uploadfile = $folder.rand(). '-'. basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:'; 
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";

$db = new SQLite3($uploadfile);
if ($db->lastErrorMsg() != 'not an error') {
    print "Database Error: " . $db->lastErrorMsg() . "<br />";    
}

$sql ="SELECT * FROM projects";
$result = $db->query($sql);
if ($db->lastErrorMsg() != 'not an error') {
    print "Database Error: " . $db->lastErrorMsg() . "<br />"; 
  }
```

this is my error 
/var/www/uploads/79316479-db.sqlite
Database Error: no such table: projects

Comment: are you sure you are referring to the proper database, friend?

Comment: im not sure how to get that information mu is too short. and yes i think so but when i try to echo $db it says it cant be converted to string so im not sure how to check that

Comment: Perhaps is a permissions issue.. If it is uploaded via post what permissions should the directory that holds the new sqlite folder have and what permissions should /var/www have (where the script sits)

Comment: Ok I tried it again with that create directory part at the top and it worked